# AngularJS multiple select box not being filled in

Tags: angularjs

I have a multiple select box with a model attached to it. [Here is a JSFiddle of my basic setup](http://jsfiddle.net/robkom/95yxj/17/).
As you can see, everything works as it should - values that are in my tags dataset automatically appear in my multiple select box (which has been made into a 'tag box' using jQuery Chosen).

The problem arises when I change the source of my tags data from being hardcoded into the JS, to being retrieved via an API call.

If I replace everything inside `myController` with the below code, the correct data is still send to the view, but it no longer automatically fills/selects the items in the multiple select.

```
var path = 'http://example.com/api/tags';
$http.get(path).success(function(data) {
    $scope.tags = data;

    $scope.createForm = {};
    $scope.createForm.tags = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.tags.length; i++)
    {
        $scope.createForm.tags[i] = $scope.tags[i].id;
    }
});
```

The data I am retrieving from the API call is in the exact same format as I had for the hardcoded value. What could the problem be? I want the behaviour to be the same whether the tags data is being hardcoded or loaded form an external source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once chosen is initialised, you have to trigger the update whenever the model is changed:

```
$(elem).trigger("chosen:updated");
```

And watch for any changes to your model, inside the directive:

```
myApp.directive("ngChosen", function ($timeout) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {

            scope.$watch(function () {
                return ngModel.$modelValue;
            }, function (newValue) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    // TRIGGER CHOSEN UPDATE
                    $(elem).trigger("chosen:updated");
                });
            }, true);

            // INIT CHOSEN
            $timeout(function () {
                $(elem).chosen({
                    width: "240px"
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/HbPVSWb9nvV2ecHibaXw?p=preview)**